# Toggle alarm to scare intruders?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

My coworkers always tell me to lock my Mac when I get up from my desk, or they'll mess with it. I think it's pretty obnoxious that I have to lock my computer each time I get up for anything, and of course, they messed with some of my settings recently.

I was thinking that, to get back at them, I'd purposefully leave my computer unlocked, but toggle some sort of siren to trigger if any button is pushed (except for some kind of preset escape sequence to disable the alarm). Is there some sort of app that would help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following software may be useful for what you wish to achieve:

- [Watchmac](http://bloo7.com/watchmac/)
- [SecuritySpy](http://www.bensoftware.com/securityspy/)

Watchmac has the ability to play an alert tone when someone tries to guess a password, or enters any incorrect password. The downside is that the Mac has to be locked for this function to work.

SecuritySpy is primarily designed for network security camera surveillance, but I do know that it will allow you to use your Mac's Built-in iSight camera to detect motion, and can sound an alarm when motion is detected. SecuritySpy does not require you to have you Mac in any locked state.

Answer (score 2):

Might be interesting if you have a MacBook...

http://mac360.com/2011/05/free-add-motion-detector-security-to-your-mac/

> [iAlertU](http://ialertu.sourceforge.net/) is an alarm system for your Apple MacBook that uses the built
>   in motion detection to trigger the alarm and the iSight to capture the
>   image of the thief. Among many other features, it incorporates the
>   ability for users with iPhone, iPad, or iPod Touch to connect to and
>   control iAlertU remotely.

Comment: It was only a quick suggestion of something that the poster might have been interested in. Not a definite answer. He did not sate whether he has a MacBook or not, so might not be relevant, and as such might not be correct. That will be for the OP to decide, not me to convince them that it is the right thing to do. At least I took the time to have a quick think about it...

Comment: now it should be ok as a answer in here.

Comment: Thanks for editing my answer @Buscar웃, I did not think I would of had to do that since it was all in the link.. Now I know.